# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (8)

Tags: троллинг, преподавание

Небуквенный орфографический символ "-" (дефис) не отличается от технологического символа "-" (знак переноса). Поэтому, я не вижу ничего плохого в том, чтобы символ "-" использовался в технологических целях, включая:

1) представление слов в виде последовательностей слогов (например: "молоко" = "мо-ло-ко"),

2) разъяснения учащимся русских слов (например, "матьимачеха" = "мать-и-мачеха").

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли технологическое использование символа "-" хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

1. По моим сведениям, русский язык - официальный язык Казахстана. Разумеется, я не планирую создавать препятствия для обучения казахов русскому языку. Более того, в русском языке должны быть средства для обучения русскому языку тех лиц, чей родной язык отличается от русского языка.
2. Когда же stopkran организует митинг в защиту анджелы дефис?

Comment: Ща я тебе организую... новую меточку!

Comment: Послушайте ворона,  
А может быть собака,  
А может быть корова,  
Ах как хороша.  
У вас такие перья,  
**У вас рога такие,  
Копыта очень стройные**  
И добрая душа.  
А если вы споете,  
А может быть залаете,  
А может замычите?  
Коровы ведь мычат!  
То вам седло большое,  
Ковер и телевизор  
В подарок сразу врУчат,  
А может быть вручАт?

Answer (score 0):

[@Галактион](/users/996/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD), даже если эти символы визуально неразличимы, они разные. Они несут разное смысловое значение и называются по-разному. Также для того, чтобы компьютер и автоматизированные системы могли эти символы различать, они обозначаются разными кодами. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [обзорную](http://habrahabr.ru/post/20588/) статью, которая объясняет различие между этими символами.

Comment: Прочёл при визуально неразличимые символы "-" и "-", которые несут разное смысловое значение. Я не возражаю, чтобы автор "обзорной статьи", упомянутой Вами, называл символ "-" дефисоминусом.